# Is server-side user agent detection/sniffing bad?

Tags: browser, user-agent, browser-detection

Client-side user agent detection [is known to be bad](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/) and [discouraged in favor of feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent). However, is it also bad to react differently based on the incoming [user agent field in a HTTP request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Use_in_HTTP)?

An example would be sending smaller or larger images based on whether the incoming user agent is mobile or desktop.

Comment: I don't think it's as much **bad** as it is **unreliable**

Comment: if think this is why you see "Mozilla" in every UA string. To answer your question, I think you should offer choice, like sites do nowadays: They redirect mobile users but still offer them to view the "normal" site.

Comment: don't consider just useragent. Fingerprint analysis of the browser, as google et al do

Comment: This entire question can be answered by reading [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970800/is-server-side-useragent-detection-bad#comment12880101_10063628) which is to say... @Raynos I think you know your own answer.... There is a use for it... however due to its lack of reliability we should not use it for anything other than statistical tracking.

Comment: @rlemon the question is more about server-side userAgent handling, when it's acceptable. I'm more looking for reading material on the subject

Comment: @Raynos ahhh. ok, I was just confused by your question; because it seems you already have a good handle on why we should not use it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think it depends what your motivation is. For example, in the mobile web sector what you are attempting to do is provide the user with something that looks sensible on their platform. Why be concerned about what user-agent the user is reporting, when it is purely for their own benefit? If they go to the effort of tricking you with a different user-agent, then they are the only person that suffers. The main trouble of course is false positives; it's not entirely reliable.

I follow the argument that you should not rely on it as such, but mobile developers are under attack from generic broad statements like this. Yes there are good alternatives, but across every browser you can imagine, this information can actually be useful at some point as the certainty begins to degrade.

What you certainly don't ever do with any plain-text header is use it to facilitate access control.

User agent detection is considered bad when there are better alternatives, but there is certainly no harm in including it in a detection process which degrades gracefully in certainty.

The issue I have with the whole process is that we are caught up in providing the user something sensible, but never seem to think it's acceptable to ask when you are uncertain. If you are uncertain about the user-agent, why not ask once and store? You can use the user-agent as a guideline.

So to conclude my thoughts, essentially the user-agent header is unreliable, so it is bad to **rely** on it. This doesn't mean you can't extract a degree of valuable information from it where more reliable options leave you in an uncertain state. In general it's wrong to conclude that it is bad. It's simply what you do with this information that makes it bad or not.

## Update

After seeing your updates to the question, I have the following comments to contribute.
Do I want to be sniffing image requests and providing the client with an image based on user agent?

If this is the only variable then maybe it could work, but it's rarely the case that the only thing you are varying is the images. I don't want to detect per request because **I want to serve the client a coherent solution**. This means I served them a page that causes them to request the correct resources. This page yields a single coherent solution for all of the integrated resources. All variations in this document work together for a particular view.

I respect that the chance of the user-agent string changing mid-view is so slim it doesn't seem worth worrying about. However adopting this principle also reduces the number of times you need to perform browser/platform detection, which can only be beneficial. This allows you to switch views on the client much more easily. If the client says actually you got the view wrong, I am a tablet not a phone, how do you go about correcting that? You serve the user a better page, otherwise you will need to be spoofing headers for your image requests... terrible idea. **Don't use the user-agent string to serve generic resources like images**.

## Potential improvements

Platform identification is a very active area of modern developments in the web. As computing becomes more ubiquitous and platforms vary much more widely, our need to understand the platforms we are serving increases. I think the general solution to this problem under the current conditions is going to fall on fingerprinting and statistical analysis.

Consider this application - [akinator.com](http://akinator.com) - Notice how the statistical analysis from a huge set of sparse data is annoyingly accurate. In a limited environment (the set of browser configurations), you can imagine that we could ask the client's browser some questions. We then perform a statistical analysis on the response in some n-dimensional feature space. Using the user-agent as a dimension of this space is going to be useful and self limiting, depending on the results that you find. If it's largely inaccurate then it will see a large spread, and the amount of worth you derive from it will be self limiting.

Of course your ability to derive any value from this statistical model requires you to be able to obtain some verified truths. This could be, for example, running a JavaScript test-suite to detect client side js capabilities, or indeed, in uncertainty, you can actually ask the user to tell you what their platform is.

-------
For further reading I'd refer you to this article by Mozilla

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent

> Today, looking for these strings are the only way to know that the
> device runs on a mobile device (resp. a tablet) before serving the
> HTML.

Comment: Actually, reading your statistical approach (this is a very common and entirely workable one, by the way), I realize that the most correct strategy is _an exhaustive test suite_: for each browser release, subject it to the full gamut of standards tests and use this to construct a signature sufficient for testing. From that set of signatures, construct a search tree to branch and minimize the number of detections per client. This requires users to enable all of their capabilities (allowing, for example, Javascript to run), but a simple prompt to do so would be more than sufficient.

Comment: As to your suggestion to ask the user, I don't believe this quite generalizes. The overlap between users whom have modified their user agent and ones that will _explicitly lie_ on direct prompting is high enough to discard such a system for consideration. Still, in an abstract sense, it's worth considering for cases where the user agent cannot be determined -- for example, when a proxy gateway is between the user and the requested page content. So, this is workable, but in a more limited capacity, I think.

Comment: My concerns regarding the statistical approach extends beyond the usual considerations for a user-agent detection mechanism. Suppose I have an exhaustive yet expensive test suite I would like to use in order to identify a set of necessary client side polyfills for example. To run this suite on the client side is an expense at the user's cost. The statistical approach, assuming accurate for a small fingerprint of readily available information (which includes the user-agent string) can reduce the detection time significantly.

Comment: Agreed. If we generalize the detections from the exhaustive approach and perform, for example, simple [Bayesian inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference), we can come to a fingerprinting solution quite quickly and effectively. Oh, how fun! Someone, somewhere, should set to working on that.

Comment: I don't assume anything about the nature or worth of any of the data the browser is providing. I use the availability of a accurate, truth identifying test suite running on the client, and a collection of easily identifiable portions of information to produce a statistical model, which naturally rights itself in terms of worth. I can also conclude to a measured degree of statistical accuracy the chance that I have identified the capabilities of this user agent correctly. Over time, reliance on the test suite decreases and the reliable model establishes itself from real world data.

Comment: (And yes, we need this, now.)

Answer (score 4):

**It depends.** Using the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) as the sole signal to branch the logic of your server-level code is dubious at best and insecure at worst, but it works for defining the rote capabilities of particular classes of browser and serving content to match their needs when the vanilla agent is supplied.

The scenario you've sketched out is a perfect illustration of this. Attempting to detect mobile browsers and downscale the content you send to them at the server level is *entirely appropriate*, because you're trying to adapt the user experience to fit their needs better (for example, by providing smaller images and better content flow to fit within the constraints of a smaller screen) while balancing them with the needs of your server (sending smaller images, thus generating less load and less bandwidth over the line). This strategy just needs refinement.

There are a few design principles you should *always* follow here to ensure your practice of user agent detection isn't seen as dubious by your users:

- *Always* provide the ability to view the full version of your site and plan your load profile accordingly. Otherwise, you *will* have people attempt to circumvent this by changing their agent.
- *Always* clearly define the modifications of your site content when you create a modal view. This will clear up any [FUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt) surrounding the changes you may or may not have made.
- *Always* provide paths to the alternate versions of your site. For example, use something like `http://mobile.example.org` for migrating people to the mobile version, making the design-level assumption that when this path is requested, it's been *explicitly* asked for by your audience.
- *Reward* users for providing their correct agent credentials to you, by offering a better experience for them in terms of content and performance. Users will be happier when you've anticipated their needs and given them snappier performance on the version of the site they're browsing.
- *Avoid* abuse and manual redirection patterns. For example, don't block them with a big horking flyout advertisement for your mobile app when you detect they're running iOS. (Admittedly, this is a pet peeve of mine.)
- *Never* restrict access to areas of the site on a user agent basis (opting instead to sternly warn users about what won't work if they go off the rails and drafting your support policy around it). For example, many of us fondly remember changing our agents for sites "that work best in Internet Explorer," disallowing all other browsers. You shouldn't become one more example of this bad practice if it can be avoided.

In short: **providing the correct user agent is a decision by the user.** You can use this to define a default experience for users choosing to run their clients plain vanilla or ones that don't know any better. The goal here is to reward your users with not providing a false user agent, by giving them the options they need and the experience they desire while balancing their needs with your own. Anything beyond that *will* cause them to balk, and as such, should be considered extremely dubious.

You can certainly try to detect the browser [by other means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasploit_Project), but this is still an area of open research. Browser capabilities and fingerprints change as they compete on features, and attempting to play catch-up to optimize performance is often, currently, intractable.

I concur with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063997/517815) on the use of statistical analysis, so don't take me wrong here. But, as someone that actively works in this area, I can tell you there's no magic bullet that will give you perfect classification certainty. Heuristics, however, can and will help you balance load more effectively, and to that end, browser interrogation strategies can and do have use to you once you've clearly defined an acceptable rate for error.

Answer (score 2):

In "standard-browser" scenario it is *not bad* BUT it is *not reliable* since a lot of browsers offer the user some config option/plugin/whatever to modify the user-agent.

In such a situation I would implement something similar to facebook - they detect based on UA (and possibly other things a.k.a. as "fingerprint analysis") whether to redirect to a mobbile version (i.e. http://m.facebook.com/...) or not (i.e. http://www.facebook.com...). At the same time they offer a URL param `m2w` which overrides this redirection mechanism.

Depending on the mobile carrier it might even happen that they have some content-aware proxy/cache which does scale/recompress images on-the-fly and appears on your end as a "normal" borwser...

Thinking of scenarios outside the browser... for example if you are serving some specific protocol (like WebDAV) this might be the only option to have some sort of "platform-specific" behaviour (for example the difference between OS X and Windows).

Comment: Redirection to a mobile version or having a seperate mobile website is a known anti pattern and a bad example ;).

Comment: @Raynos I don't fully agree but then the only option left is to detect client-side (NOT user-ganet, but javascript-based feature detection) and inform the server which capabilities have been found...

Comment: The real option for mobile is media queries, progressive enhancement and responsive design.

Comment: @Raynos Several mobile borwsers are capable of JS these days and CSS media queries won't detect all relevant features - so *the real option* is a combination of both IMHO.