# CSS Classes instead of Media Queries

Tags: css, media-queries

Just wondering if there's any method/techniques that allow you to to replace media queries with class names.

For example

```
.header { width: 100% }
.tablet .header { width: 50%; float: left; }
.phone .header { width: 100%; max-width: 320px;}
```

so the .tablet or .phone get applied to the html tag like `<html class="phone">`

Would there be an method/preparation to get something like this to work? or would it require using JavaScript to change the class on the element?

Thanks

Comment: that would require javascript. twitter bootstrap are doing something similar with their classes. See [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/css/#responsive-utilities)

Comment: You could do this with some server-side code, but it might be a pain to keep updated. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970800/is-server-side-useragent-detection-bad#answer-10063997) has some good information

Comment: @Dogoku TW Bootstrap uses `classes` inside `media queries`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing will require javascript, since the html needs to change in order for that to happen

There are tools out there to help you react to media queries in javascript, such as the amazing **[Enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)**

But if you are looking for something which requires no js and you can use SASS, i would suggest using **[CSS Wizardy's responsive grid](https://github.com/csswizardry/csswizardry-grids)** which can help you generate your layout as you want it

We are using it to build our own mobile optimized embeds and we found it very powerful and easy to use.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could just have different style sheets used for different devices. Use same classes, no media queries

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 901px)" href="css/large.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />
```